# Rcaller executing a function from .R file

Tags: java, r, rcaller

I am trying to execute a R file from java, here is the code i have tried.

```
RCaller caller = new RCaller();
RCode code = new RCode();  
caller.setRscriptExecutable("D:\\R\\R-3.0.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe");    
code.clear();
caller.setRCode(code);
code.R_source("D:\\Data\\Workspace\\Cpackage\\try.R");
caller.setRCode(code);
caller.runOnly();
```

**try.R file**

```
myinput<-function(){
//loading a csv file,reading it and creating an excel file(Working when it is run from r directly)
}

myinput()
```

The above rcaller java code does not do anything.Please help if i am doing anything wrong,i need to do this very badly. If there is anyother way to achieve this please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

RCaller does not change the Java path format that is given in

```
code.R_source("D:\\Data\\Workspace\\Cpackage\\try.R");
```

to R format. This produces a R code like

```
source("D:\\Data\\Workspace\\Cpackage\\try.R")
```

so you need to change it to

```
code.R_source("D:/Data/Workspace/Cpackage/try.R");
```

It is good to have a look at the source code at [Rcaller source](https://code.google.com/p/rcaller/source/browse/RCaller/src/main/java/rcaller/RCode.java), it can be seen that

```
public void R_source(String sourceFile) {
    addRCode("source(\"" + sourceFile + "\")\n");
}
```

defines the function with literally given R file as an R string.

Comment: Tried, but no difference.

Comment: But when i do caller.runAndReturnResult("myinput()"); instead of caller.runonly() it gives Can not handle R results due to : rcaller.exception.RCallerParseException: Can not parse the R output: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Error.

Comment: And you don't need to use RCaller for this. You don't handle any returned value so just use Java's Runtime and Process classes.

Comment: caller.runAndReturnResult("myinput()"); is not a correct use of RCaller. Please read the blog entries and home page to get an idea of using it.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:/Data/Workspace/Cpackage/try.R"); is what you suggested rite? it gives java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:/Data/Workspace/Cpackage/try.R": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application...if i am doing anything wrong,please help!

Comment: My suggestion is to learn Windows first, than Java and finally R and RCaller for doing these stuff.